# is there any method for WALA to slice several jars

Tags: java, slice, wala

i am a green hand for WALA.
i am trying to slice a jar for hdfs, but it is corelated with other parts of hadoop like hadoop commom. so i wonder if there is any method to slice several jars or slice one and the slice statement including the calls from other jars.

if you have any ideas about it thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I got it. We can solve this problem through adding several paths to the jar path which we choose to slice, like:

```
String path = "./test.jar;./test01.jar";
```

Quite simple.